# Telerik Upload fails in IE11 Load balancer

Tags: c#, telerik, internet-explorer-11, telerik-mvc

We are using Telerik.Upload(), using windows authentication, from IE11/10  fails to upload in the load balancer . With a single server it works fine. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication supports two authentication protocols, Kerberos and NTLM, which are defined in the `<providers>` element. By default providers are configured with Negotiate followed by NTLM. IIS will try to perform Kerberos first with a fallback to NTLM. See Benjamin Perkins' blog post, [Integrated Windows Authentication with Negotiate](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2011/09/14/integrated-windows-authentication-with-negotiate/), for an explanation of how this works.

This may be an issue with how a load balancer impacts Kerberos' normal behavior. You may need to set up a domain account to run your application pools in IIS and add an appropriate Service Principal Name for your load-balanced DNS name. See Stefan Nuxoll's very thorough blog post at [Kerberos Authentication with Load-Balanced IIS](http://blog.snuxoll.com/post/82358808839/kerberos-authentication-with-load-balanced-iis) for more information.

NTLM for Integrated Windows Authentication is connection oriented so if your session connects to the other server when the upload is started the authentication will fail. See [sol10477: Optimizing NTLM traffic in BIG-IP 10.x or later](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/10000/400/sol10477.html) for one example of how NTLM and a load balancer behave together.

You can use Fiddler to see the authentication being exchanged in the HTTP headers for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks much! But i dont understand the 2nd point completely. It works fine with the same settings in IE9. When we started using IE11 in load balancer it doesnt work.   As soon as the upload method is called, it is returning 401 unauthorized error. It is using NTLM authentication...we have windows authentication enabled for our site.

Comment: I suspected that it was a 401 error, but your question did not specify. The 2nd part was in case you were experiencing other problems, but also can be used to verify the HTTP headers being exchanged. l'll modify the answer based on the new information.

Comment: Also, what brand of load balancer are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not sure about the load balancer brand as it is managed by a different group.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm afraid that's the best I can do for you right now as any final solution is likely to involve configuration on both the web server and load balancer.